# webpack/react/babel doesn't compile JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I know there are a lot of similar questions but I didn't found the solution and some of them are old so they don't apply.

I've created a Webpack environmental for react but doesn't compile JSX syntax.

I'm using:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"react": "^16.7.0",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0",
```

In my babel.config.js I have:

```
  ...
  'presets': [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        'targets': {
          'chrome': 61,
        },
        'modules': false,
        'useBuiltIns': 'usage'
      },
      '@babel/preset-react'
    ]
  ],
  ...
```

I can compile react code like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
require('./scss/main.scss')

const e = React.createElement

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      liked: false
    }
  }

  render () {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.'
    }

    return e(
      'button',
      {
        onClick: () => this.setState({
          liked: true
        })
      },
      'Like'
    )
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container')
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer)
```

but when I tried to use JSX

```
const name = 'Name';
const element = <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

it complain about the `<` of the `h1`

Comment: Unless there's an extremely compelling reason not to, just use [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/).

Comment: @ChrisG not using the CLI allows to have a deeper understanding of the whole framework and allows to tweak certain options. [Making a React app from scratch](https://github.com/ninofiliu/react-redux-webpack-typescript) is quite valuable to learn about the whole process hidden by the CLI.

Comment: @ChrisG a compelling reason to NOT use create-react-app is that it helps you actually understand what's going on under the hood. It's good to learn the fundamentals before using a tool that abstracts them all away from you. OP did you add a JSX loader to your `webpack.config.js`? You need one to tell it to tranpsile `.jsx` files

Comment: @Jayce444 it suppose to be included in `@babel/preset-env` isn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your `@babel/preset-react` outside your config for `@babel/preset-env` (move it outside the array), like this:

```
presets: [
  ["@babel/preset-env", {...}],
  "@babel/preset-react",
]
```

`@babel/preset-react` should be on the same level (top level for `presets`) as your `@babel/preset-env`.

Answer (score 0):

`const element` in your code is not a valid React component.
You need to return a function and always start component names with a capital letter.

```
// Always import React at the top of the file!
import React from 'react';

function Person(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

const element = <Person name="Name of the person" />;

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

More on components here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Ok, i know this way but  the documentation say that I can also use the other way https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html the JSX example it comes from there